# Geospatial application in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysqli, geospatial

For my next Ruby on Rails-project I will have to store and query geospatial data. More precisely I want to do the following things:

- Store a few thousand lat/lon-pairs in the DB.
- Query if a point is within a certain radius of any point.
- Query if a point is within a rectangle (that spans between two points)
- Possibly query if a point is within an arbitrary polygon.
- Possibly store a high amount of points in a sort of "position log" (up to a few hundreds a second) and retrieve them later of course.

Another very important query is:

- Find me the nearest n stored points in relation to a lat/lon pair.

What is the most pain-free combination of components to accomplish that? I care about a quick implementation and very fast queries.

I have found [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/lest/geospatial-applications-on-rails) and the author seems to favor Postgres and the activerecord-postgis-adapter, but perhaps there are other worthwhile opinions.

This is just a small prototype project, but I already have MySQL running, so I am interested in experiences with that. Or ist Postgres + PostGIS definitely the way to go? And I know that MongoDB makes it easy to get started with Geo-data, however, this time I want to use a relational database.

Any input is very appreciated.

Comment: -1? Apparently this was not a good question then. Anyway, I went with MySQL and everything is fine so far. Here are the relevant gems in my Gemfile: mysql2, spatial-adapter and geokit-rails3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL also supports GIS. Though MSSQL and Postgres have excellent library support for this, MySQL can also perform well. Check the [***function list MySQL provides***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html).

- MySQL: Uses Geography datatype for both GIS and planner calculation. **Documentation**-> Good
- MSSQL: Has both Geography and Geometry datatype. **Documentation**->Great. **Help**-> Awesome
- Postgres: Has both Geography and Geometry datatype. **Documentation**->Awesome. **Help**-> Good

Choose wise :)

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I have decided to go with MySQL, my solution is in the question comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have used MongoDB with mongoid. does a great job. Also, try using in elasticsearch (tire gem) for geo search.

Comment: Yes, I know MongoDB does a good job, but I wanted something relational. But thanks for the tip with elasticsearch.